# Using Counters in cassandra for multiple java instances

Tags: java, cassandra

Hi I am planning to use Counters  for getting a human readable unique number  in Cassandra .I have my java application running on two servers (2 instances).How can i ensure that any request at anytime fetches me a unique counter value?

Answer (score 1):

Counters are not sequences.  Use UUIDs to generate unique identifiers instead: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/webhelp/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html

Comment: Hi,We need some text in Human readable form here.As we hand over that unique identifier to our customers as receipt numbers.If we go with UUID its really difficult for customers to quote this number back to us.Eg:cd62fbd0-0965-11e3-b096-005056877bfb would be difficult for any user to quote back where as a number like 1001 or 1002 is much more user freindly.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing counters i.e (read & write) are atomic job, so  you need not have to fetch the column and then increment or decrement.

e.g `update #CF set cnt1=cnt+1, cnt2=cnt2+10 where field='SOMETHING';`

Comment: So suppose i Have 2 instances Instance 1:-gets the current counter value updates it and then fetches it again,Instance 2:- gets the value when instance 1 started.How can we prevent this condition?